# Are there C++ versions of PHP's fsockopen, fread, fwrite, fclose?

Tags: php, c++, windows, sockets, tcp

Are there C++ versions of PHP's fsockopen, fread, fwrite, fclose or anything similar?

I'm using Windows (MFC) and TCP if that changes anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are analogous functions for all of thoes take a look at the [winsock api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741394%28VS.85%29.aspx) for particular functions.

MFC is a wrapper for much of the win32 api and has a [Csoket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxzt95kb%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [CAsyncSocket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3d46645f%28VS.80%29.aspx) abstract sockets.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)

Answer (score 1):

A level above what yo uasked for is libCurl

http://curlpp.org/index.php/examples/48-example-01